# Cannot find name ''content" in typescript

Tags: typescript

i've  a function called `navigateToApp` , in else condition i'm passing an other function called `openModalDialog(content)` , but here the `content` is showing an error called `Cannot find name content`  what is wrong here, please help me thanks in advance

```
openModalDialog(content) {
 this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
   this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
 })
}

navigateToApp = () => {
  axios.get('*************').then(function (res) {
  if (res.data.message == "Not Found"){
    console.log("this condition....")
  }
   else {
    this.openModalDialog(content)  
  }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Where does `content` come from? It's not defined within `navigateToApp`.

Comment: Seeing only your code snippet, content is not available in the scope of navigateToApp. It is available inside the scope of openModalDialog. You either have to pass it to navigateToApp or make it available globally.

Comment: i follow this link to create a modal box `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples` , here i used the first example

Answer (score 1):

In the comment of your question, you say you are

> i follow this link to create a modal box
> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples , here i
> used the first example

Well you can see from that example, `content` is provided as a tag in the first line of the template:

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
```

And then passed into the method in the event

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

You are bypassing the template here and calling the method directly, with no context of the template tag. This clearly is NOT going to work. You are opening a modal programatically, not from a user triggered event.

Take a look at the second example there, https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component as it will allow you to open a modal programatically.